# Is ember (Ember data) ready for productive use?

Tags: backbone.js, angularjs, ember.js

is Ember.js with Ember data ready for productive use or should I better use Angular/Backbone.js at the moment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Ember.js

is **more than ready** to use for production, it will soon hit the **1.0** milestone, and many companies are already using it for *ambitious web apps* in the field (see at the bottom of the main page on the official website http://emberjs.com for reference).

### Ember-data

in turn is a *separate* persistence library for ember which is not quite ready for production (although many are already doing it) now and you should use it only if you want to live *on the bleeding edge* and are willing to fix problems you might encounter along the way yourself, an then providing a pull request with your improvements to give back to the community. But as a rule of thumb, if your requirements are for an application which is mostly read only, then ember-data is really an awesome framework to use with a fantastic ORM built in.

### But

since ember.js uses (under the hood) jQuery you can always roll your own persistence layer  with `$.ajax`, `$.getJSON` and friends, a very good show case is http://discourse.org which is a big open source forum platform built entirely with ember.js but without ember-data, see this very enlightning blog post as a reference for this: http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html.

### Conclusion

- Should I use ember.js? A **BIG** yes!
- Should I use also ember-data as my persistence layer? A *normal* yes!

Hope this helps your decision.